# Layers from 2 stages to single Json object

Tags: kineticjs

I have 2 stages with multiple layers. I'd like to get all layers (from both stage1 and stage2) and pack them in one Json object using .toJson(). Is there a way to do that? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do that within KineticJS. You would have to use `stage.toJSON()` on both stages and then use some external method to combine the 2 separate JSON strings.

Are you trying to do this because you want to combine the 2 stages into 1 stage when you load the combined JSON string?

I recommend you use **1 Stage and 2 Layers** KineticJS structure instead. Layers are sizeable so you should be able to fit them to your needs.  This would solve your problem as `stage.toJSON()` in this structure would capture all the data between all the layers inside the stage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I'm actually trying to do is a pdf annotator. So pdf document may have more than 1 page and I'm adding stage to every page and then layer to every stage. As long as I have one page only I'm fine. Just sending layer.toJson to the server. Anyway, your suggestion to combine Json strings seems to be good.

Comment: No problem, if that answers your question please accept the answer. I still recommend, if you are able to, to stick to 1 stage and multiple layers though!

Comment: One stage would be ok but not for my multistage pdf . I need to add a new shape on button click . So my '1 stage/1 page approach makes it easy to distinguish where to place the shape.

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for me. I've created an array and added all json strings (layers) to it. Then just sending it to the server

```
 for (var i = 1; i <= PDFView.pages.length; i++) {
    var lr = layers[i - 1]
    jsonShapes.push(lr.toJSON());

}
```